# debug assertion failed in file correct_internal_string_templates.h

Tags: assertion

I am using an in-house code, and running it in VS2019 & 2022 in debug mode. However, an error occurs as follows:

```
Debug assertion failed! 

Program: .vssolution\select\x64\debug\select.exe 

File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\inc\correct_internal_string_templates.h 

Line:218 expression:(l*buffer is too small* && 0) 

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the visual c++ documentation on asserts. (press retry to debug the application) site:stackoverflow.com site:stackoverflow.com site:stackoverflow.com site:stackoverflow.com
```

However, this code has also been implemented in my colleague's laptop without this error, while another colleague running it with the same error that I have encountered.

After clicked 'Retry' in the error dialog box, the code breaks here 'IF (LANGUE.GE.0.AND.LANGUE.LT.2) GOTO 005':

```
      LANGUE=0
      IF (ICONVI.EQ.0) THEN
    4    WRITE(6,2000)
 2000    FORMAT ('  ENGLISH  : ENTER 0'/
     .           '  FRANCAIS : ENTRER 1'//)
         READ(5,*) LANGUE
        IF (LANGUE.GE.0.AND.LANGUE.LT.2) GOTO 005    !!!--break here--!!!
         WRITE (6,2001) LANGUE
 2001    FORMAT (' **** ERRONEOUS VALUE - VALEUR ERRONNEE ****',I5//)
         GOTO 004
      ENDIF
    5 CONTINUE
```

In the Call Stack window, it shows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiBpK.png)

I suspected my colleague, who run the code without problem, uses different library that does not include the 'assert' implementation.